# How to reload base64 animated GIF?

Tags: javascript, c#, base64, gif, cefsharp

I use base64 animated GIF on my web page, when I try to reload page GIF still show last frame. How can I reload GIF from its beginning? 
I tried use JS to clear innerHTML and then assign it back to my base64 GIF, but nothing happened.
I am also using C# and CefSharp (tried use Refresh() and chromeBrowser.GetBrowser().Reload()), would be great to get any tips how to make GIF play from its beginnig.
I use base64 because I cannot store image on users hard drive or Web, but I need to put this image into HTML, which can be loaded by CefSharp using C#. If there are any other ways to use animated image in HTML without storing it on HDD or web, please give me some tips too.

**Update**:

I decided to leave base64 because big size of my gifs (>25 Mb) cause lags and problems with reload. 
I use CEFSharp  v55-pre01 and found new problem. 
What do I have:

1. Main menu
2. Form 1 (with cefsharp browser, which loads gif by code automatically)
3. Form 2 (with cefsharp browser, loads same gif)

From main menu I call Form 1, when Form 1 initialize, Form 1 create hidden Form 2. 
First form initialize Cef

```
if (!Cef.IsInitialized)
{
   Cef.Initialize(settings);
}
```

Each form in constructor initialize own browser

```
chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("");
Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
```

Problem appear in situation, when I close second form (no mater is 2nd form shown or not) and dispose both forms and call `Cef.Shutdown()`. When I try open back first form from menu my app crashes.
Error appear at second form constructor on line `chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("");` with such text:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in CefSharp.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: If the contents of the base64 string haven't changed then you'll need to reload the ignoring the cached value. If you look closer you'll see reload has an optional parameter

Comment: html with base64 stored in variable, I tried use reload with ignoring the cached value, and even load whole html page from variable after it, but still GIF is frozen at last frame.

Comment: Sounds somewhat like the renderer process crashed, check the processes that are running.

Comment: Processes are OK, but I noticed now interesting thing. If I call reload in loop (for example 5 times in a row) 3 situations may happen: 1) frozen last frame 2) empty 3) GIF reloaded OK. Same happen even if I use Reload without ignore cache. As additional info, If I Load html with other base64 gif next to first one, new gif plays ok, but if I try load again first gif after second one, it is loaded frozen at last frame.

Comment: Test in an equivalent version of chrome

Comment: thank You for your replies, I updated my question

Comment: Go to the CefSharp wiki and read the general usage guide, there is a section on startup and shutdown.

Comment: You helped me a lot, In 2nd form for no reason I used Cef.Shutdown(), successfully forgot about it, and it's caused my problem.